# HBase Java client API code not responding while connecting to remote HBase server

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I have created a HBase cluster with one name node and two data nodes. I could able to execute queries from the Hbase shell from within the name node. However while trying to execute code from HBase Java API, the code just stands still and makes no progress. Attached below is the log info. The program neither terminate nor hangs out. Please let me know if I am missing something.

```
13/11/14 17:04:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.5-1392090, built on 09/30/2012 17:52 GMT
    13/11/14 17:04:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=css99362-Veriton-Series
    13/11/14 17:04:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.7.0_17
    13/11/14 17:04:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    13/11/14 17:04:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=/home/javaWorld/jdk1.7.0_17/jre
    13/11/14 17:04:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.class.path=/home/codeWorld/daaas-labs/daaas-dwh/target/classes:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.0/scala-library-2.10.0.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/org/apache/hbase/hbase/0.94.11/hbase-0.94.11.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/com/yammer/metrics/metrics-core/2.1.2/metrics-core-2.1.2.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/11.0.2/guava-11.0.2.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.6/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils-core/1.8.0/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/com/github/stephenc/high-scale-lib/high-scale-lib/1.1.1/high-scale-lib-1.1.1.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.1/commons-io-2.1.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.5/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/org/apache/avro/avro/1.5.3/avro-1.5.3.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/org/xerial/snappy/snappy-java/1.0.3.2/snappy-java-1.0.3.2.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/org/apache/avro/avro-ipc/1.5.3/avro-ipc-1.5.3.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/org/jboss/netty/netty/3.2.4.Final/netty-3.2.4.Final.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.7/velocity-1.7.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/org/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper/3.4.5/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/org/apache/thrift/libthrift/0.8.0/libthrift-0.8.0.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.1.2/httpclient-4.1.2.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.1.3/httpcore-4.1.3.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jruby-complete/1.6.5/jruby-complete-1.6.5.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty/6.1.26/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-util/6.1.26/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jsp-2.1/6.1.14/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jsp-api-2.1/6.1.14/jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/servlet-api-2.5/6.1.14/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.8.8/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.8.8/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-jaxrs/1.8.8/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-xc/1.8.8/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.4.3/slf4j-api-1.4.3.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.4.3/slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/tomcat/jasper-compiler/5.5.23/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/tomcat/jasper-runtime/5.5.23/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/org/jamon/jamon-runtime/2.3.1/jamon-runtime-2.3.1.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.4.0a/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.8/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-json/1.8/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jettison/jettison/1.1/jettison-1.1.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3-1/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.8/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.1/jaxb-api-2.1.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/stax/stax-api/1.0.1/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-core/1.0.3/hadoop-core-1.0.3.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/xmlenc/xmlenc/0.52/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-math/2.1/commons-math-2.1.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/commons-net/commons-net/1.4.1/commons-net-1.4.1.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/commons-el/commons-el/1.0/commons-el-1.0.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jets3t/jets3t/0.7.1/jets3t-0.7.1.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/net/sf/kosmosfs/kfs/0.3/kfs-0.3.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/hsqldb/hsqldb/1.8.0.10/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.jar:/home/css99362/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jdt/core/3.1.1/core-3.1.1.jar
    13/11/14 17:04:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/home/javaWorld/jdk1.7.0_17/jre/lib/i386/server:/home/javaWorld/jdk1.7.0_17/jre/lib/i386:/home/javaWorld/jdk1.7.0_17/jre/../lib/i386:/home/javaWorld/jdk1.7.0_17/jre/lib/i386/client:/home/javaWorld/jdk1.7.0_17/jre/lib/i386::/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
    13/11/14 17:04:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
    13/11/14 17:04:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
    13/11/14 17:04:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
    13/11/14 17:04:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=i386
    13/11/14 17:04:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=3.2.0-56-generic-pae
    13/11/14 17:04:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=css99362
    13/11/14 17:04:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/css99362
    13/11/14 17:04:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/home/codeWorld/daaas-labs/daaas-dwh
    13/11/14 17:04:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=hbase-master:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
    13/11/14 17:04:58 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this process is 21212@css99362-Veriton-Series
    13/11/14 17:04:58 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server hbase-master/10.8.27.34:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
    13/11/14 17:04:58 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to hbase-master/10.8.27.34:2181, initiating session
    13/11/14 17:04:58 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server hbase-master/10.8.27.34:2181, sessionid = 0x142564ef3a5000d, negotiated timeout = 180000
    13/11/14 17:04:58 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Closed zookeeper sessionid=0x142564ef3a5000d
    13/11/14 17:04:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x142564ef3a5000d closed
    13/11/14 17:04:58 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
    13/11/14 17:04:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=hbase-master:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
    13/11/14 17:04:58 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this process is 21212@css99362-Veriton-Series
    13/11/14 17:04:58 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server hbase-master/10.8.27.34:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
    13/11/14 17:04:58 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to hbase-master/10.8.27.34:2181, initiating session
    13/11/14 17:04:58 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server hbase-master/10.8.27.34:2181, sessionid = 0x142564ef3a5000e, negotiated timeout = 180000
```

Comment: Can you please copy and paste your code here on StackOverFlow?

Comment: Same issue here I am using the HBase book codes example   !

Comment: I'm having [same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219258/connecting-to-a-remote-hbase-instance), did you managed to solve this? it will be great if you can share your solution.